# How to provide security for website or web application rather than using https?

Tags: security, https, web, azure-web-app-service

I published my web app into Azure web application but I want to provide the security for this application.

I know by using HTTPS we can provide security for web application. I read this [link](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/website-security-tips-protect-your-site-7122853) before posting question here.

Rather than using https, are there any other techniques for providing security to web site or web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-security) mentioned about the Security Level in Azure App Service:

> **Infrastructure and platform security** - You trust Azure to have the services you need to actually run things securely in the cloud.
>
> **Application security** - You need to design the app itself securely. This includes how you integrate with Azure Active Directory, how you manage certificates, and how you make sure that you can securely talk to different services.

For Infrastructure and platform security, Azure would isolate your App Service apps and communication of sensitive datas (e.g. sql connectionstring, appId, appSecret,etc.) are always encrypted. Also, App service would provide threat management protects App Service resources from malware, DDoS, MITM, and other threats.

For Application security, you need to develop, manage your application in a security way. The frequent threats would as follows:

- SQL Injection
- Session hijacking
- Cross-site-scripting

Additionally, you could leverage [integration with Tinfoil Security](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/web-vulnerability-scanning-for-azure-app-service-powered-by-tinfoil-security/) to perform penetration testing on your app and follow the instructions to fix possible vulnerability. For a better understanding of it, you could refer to this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-security) about secure an app in Azure App Service.